# Servicemix with Karaf 4.0 Attribute 'prerequisite' is not allowed to appear in element 'feature'

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm migrating from karaf 3 to karaf 4 and I've had an issue with wrap feature while starting service-mix:

```
Karaf Pax Exam fails with Unknown protocol: wrap
```

I tried the solution from:
[Karaf Pax Exam fails with Unknown protocol: wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289763/karaf-pax-exam-fails-with-unknown-protocol-wrap)

but I'm getting:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'prerequisite' is not allowed to appear in element 'feature'.
```

The 'dirty' solution from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-4302?focusedCommentId=15153982&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15153982 is working, but I'm wondering why the prerequisite solution is not.